# Get CPU usage for past n seconds or minutes

Tags: linux, command-line, process, cpu-usage

Is there a magic command in Linux for listing the processes active in the last **past** *n* seconds by CPU usage?

To clarify: Process A is launched and it takes 5 seconds to complete, about 5 more seconds go by, *magic-command* is launched to check processes over the last 20 seconds and its output lists Process A and the amount of CPU usage it had over the previous 20 seconds.

As far as I understand commands like *top*, *ps* or *mpstat* aren't going to inspect resources used before their launch and while *find* can report which files were used in the past in a scale of minutes or hours, I won't be able to read CPU use from that data.

I believe the only way to do this is to start monitoring resource usage before the events I want to measure take place, am I wrong?

Comment: Unless there is a scheduler "callback" that allows you to trigger specific actions whenever a thread is scheduled (and for performance reasons there is none obviously), you are right (there is no other way) IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

The systat family of utilities does this sort of thing through process accounting.

For long term historical and statistical analysis, you have to enable the process accounting system, see [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/913087/sar-enable-data-collecting) answer.  Once you have enabled process accounting, you can use commands like `sadf` to extract and summarize statistics.

More immediate tools in the sysstat package include `pidstat` which can give you process activity while it is running.

Comment: do you mean that I should set sar to collect statistics every n seconds to a file and access those files to get what I need?

Comment: Yes, except that it's already set up, you just have to install and enable it.